# How to use properly redis for storing objects and retrieve them

Tags: database, data-structures, database-design, redis

I am thinking of building an app in which your database is exclusively **redis**, I have some doubts about how to save information about the objects and then obtain it again.

Redis, on its official page says that the best way to save objects is with Hashes, as follows:

```
HSET user:uuid "name" "example_name" "address" "example_address" "lang" "es en de"
```

ok this is fine but if i want to query the object for its uuid or other field(something i will definitely want to do) should i do something like this?

```
SET user:uuid user:uuid
```

And query later somehow ... it is right? I don't think so.

Also I would like to consult all the users in redis, that for example, have "lang" type "es".

What kind of query would I have to do in redis and what operations would I have to use?

I have read that I have to put the data in redis the way I want to consult them, but I do not see how to do it, can someone help me out?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you check the RediSearch module for Redis?

Comment: Nop, I want to stay with redis vanilla. I would like to use the minimum amount of software possible.

Comment: Please check Redis secondary indexes. https://redis.io/topics/indexes

Comment: In this case I think that the secondary indexes do not work for me, I mean: ZADD and ZRANGEBYSCORE work with float values ​​and the attributes of my objects are almost always strings.  I also don't think Lexicographical indexes work for my use case.

Comment: @AndoniRodriguez what you wrote as solution is also accomplished by using "secondary index". The link provides examples - it doesn't have to be sorted set or lex.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can have a valid approach.

**redis** is not a relational database and I shouldn't want queries of this type, but I still think I can manage to keep a couple of useful indexes for me.

These two indexes will behave as unique keys and will be: uuid and name and the insertion will be done as follows:

```
MULTI
HSET user:uuid "name" "example_name" "address" "example_address" "lang" "es en de"
SET user:name user:uuid
INCR user_count # this is only a counter.
EXEC
```

I can always ask redis for my "unique key" (uuid) as follows:

```
HGETALL user:uuid
```

Or for the other "unique key" using **GET** (taking advantage of the previous GET):

```
GET user:name
HGETALL user:uuid # taking user:uuid of GET value response.
```

**NOTE:** On code, I will have to do the proper logic so that the keys that I have defined as unique are really unique.

In order to check if a user has a certain lang, I think I can make good use of **SADD** and **SISMEMBER** in the following way:

```
SADD lang:es user:uuid
SISMEMBER lang:es user:uuid # if returns 1 I can use HGETALL
HGETALL user:uuid
```

I do not know if this approach can be considered a good design in redis but I have tried to avoid the use of **KEYS** or **SCAN** so as not to harm the performance of the database.